# preview of stackblitz static html project ends in ENOENT error

Tags: html, path, stackblitz

I try to share a static html template project I made. But the Problem is that I end up with this error:
`{"syscall":"","errno":2,"code":"ENOENT","path":"/var"}`

The problem occurs when I open the preview link to the project. But if the html project is still open in the stackblitz editor in the background, it works. The problem also appears when you open a static html project from scratch and then want to open the preview with your cell phone, for example.

To narrow down the problem:
I am logged into stackblitz with my Github account. So I should be able to share my projects. The ENOENT error only appears with static html projects. It seems to me that it could also be a general problem, since the error also appears on newly created projects without any change.